# How can deduct the value from table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to deduct the value of a column in a table from another table. I want if there is any issue in any item it deduct the from the other table but when i do it show the error

```
  failed 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'orderProduct'
```

View.py

```
from purchase.models import OrderRequest
from .models import GatePass

class OrderView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'inventory/orderCheck.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        orderId = self.request.GET.get('order')
        order = OrderRequest.objects.filter(pk=orderId)
        args = {'order': order}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        orderId = self.request.GET.get('order_id')
        statusAccept = self.request.POST.get('action') == "accept"
        statusReject = self.request.POST.get('action') == "reject"
        if statusReject:
            try:
                data = self.request.POST.get
                orderView = GatePass(
                    fault=data('fault'),
                    remarks=data('remarks'),
                    order_id=orderId
                )
                order = OrderRequest.order.orderProduct.quantity - orderView.fault
                order.save()
                orderView.save()
                return redirect('gatePass', 200)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse('failed {}'.format(e), 500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the attribute 'quantity' on an instance of the model. That is, you need to first get the order:

```
order = OrderRequest.objects.get(pk=orderId)
```

then

```
order = order.orderProduct.quantity - orderView.fault
```

Comment: sorry i not mention order is a foreign key in OrderRequest table and orderProduct is foreign key in order table. i am just assign ' OrderRequest.order.orderProduct.quantity - orderView.fault  ' in order variable

Comment: you still need the OrderRequest as an instance order_request = OrderRequest.objects.get(pk=orderId); order = order_request.orderProduct.quantity - orderView.fault. You are trying to access a model attribute from the class, you need to access it from an instance of the class. ie you need to 'get' your order from the db, OrderRequest.objects.get()...

Comment: through get() query it show the error "  failed OrderRequest matching query does not exist." .   When i use FIlter() query it show the error " failed 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'orderProduct' "

Comment: You dont have any data in you database that corresponds to what you are tying to get. You need to use get. You need an object. Not a queryset

Comment: failed Reverse for 'gatePass' with arguments '(200,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['gatepass$'] '  gatePass my template it show error after submit the button

Comment: there is some problem with your routing/ url patterns

Comment: when i try to update the field order_request.save(update_fields=order_request.order.orderProduct.quantity)  it show error '  failed 'int' object is not iterable  '